# Add a string into identical columns in two dataframe R

Tags: r, string

I have two dataframes (see below) and I would like to add in the first df a string '*' at the end of the identic world for the 2 column "team"  of the different dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(team=rep(c('Blue', 'Red', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Pink'), each=2),
                 pos=rep(c('G', 'F'), times=4),
                 points=round(runif(8, 4, 20),0))

View(df)

df2 <-data.frame(team=rep(c('Blue', 'Purple', 'Pink', 'Yellow'), each=2))

View(df2)
```

results expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking for elementwise comparison, use `==` to create a logical expression and then extract those elements in 'team' from 'df' and `paste` the `*` at the end

```
i1 <- df$team == df2$team 
df$team[i1] <- paste0(df$team[i1], "*")
```

If the lengths are different, then append `NA` for the shorter length vector at the end do the elementwise comparison

```
lst1 <- list(df$team, df2$team)
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
i1 <- Reduce("==", lapply(lst1, "length<-", mx))
i1[is.na(i1)] <- FALSE
df$team[i1] <- paste0(df$team[i1], "*")
```

Comment: Unless it can be assured that the teams would be in the same order, maybe `i1 <- df$team %in% df2$team` would be a safer choice?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery that was my previous choice, but it won't match "Purple" which is at a different position based on the expected

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: I forget to specify that my two tables have much more rows and have different lenght, as therefore I got this warning message when trying `i1 <- df$team == df2$team          Warning message:
In merge_species_list_flux$NameSize == diff_flux_sp$NameSize :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: @GrgLulu My original code was `df$team %in% df2$team`, but then 'Purple' would match.  are you looking for elementwise.  Then, make the lengths same by appending `NA`, i.e. `lst1 <- list(df$team, df2$team); mx <- max(lengths(lst1)); i1 <- Reduce("==", lapply(lst1, "length<-", mx))` and use the `i1[is.na(i1)] <- FALSE; `df$team[i1] <- paste0(df$team[i1], "*")`